# How do I create Upload only permission in SharePoint 2019 no edit?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, sharepoint-permissions, document-upload

Hello i hope you can help me with this question.

I don´t want a specific group of users to edit. But they should be allowed to upload their documents.

Here is my permission so far.
[image]

But when I´m trying to upload a document the error appears.

[image]

On some pages it says you need the edit permission. On others it says that the add permission is sufficient.
If I now add the edit permission, I can also upload the documents. However, these users who are allowed to upload, should not be able to edit any elements.

My only option would be to completely split the permissions on the document libraries and create a new group that only has edit permissions on these libraries.

Is there a way to allow users to upload documents without getting edit permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a permission level as following pictures show.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Test result, can upload file but cannot edit.

[image]

Comment: The same error appeard today. Thought it helped but not.